# How to append a row to a panda dataframe inside a loop without overwriting it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a class with field created with empty dataframe like:

```
import pandas as pd


class Report:
    report = pd.DataFrame()
```

inside that class I have two functions, the first one like:

```
    def create_df(self):
        column_names = ["log_file_name", "Searched_Age", 
                        "Searched_Nationality", 
                        "Searched_Service_Type",
                        "all_p0", "all_p1", "all_p2", "all_p3", 
                        "p0", "p1", "p2", "p3", 
                        "no_prop_violated"]

        # add empty dataframe to class field.
        Report.report = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

The second function is:

```
    def add_row(self, log_file_name, Searched_Age, 
                Searched_Nationality, 
                Searched_Service_Type,
                all_p0, all_p1, all_p2, 
                all_p3, p0, p1, p2, p3, no_prop_violated):

        dict_para = {'log_file_name': log_file_name,
                     'Searched_Age': Searched_Age,
                      'Searched_Nationality': Searched_Nationality,
                      'Searched_Service_Type': Searched_Service_Type,
                      'all_p0': all_p0,
                       'all_p1': all_p1,
                       'all_p2': all_p2,
                       'all_p3': all_p3,
                       'p0': p0,
                       'p1': p1,
                       'p2': p2,
                       'p3': p3,
                       'no_prop_violated': no_prop_violated}
        Report.report = Report.report.append(dict_para, ignore_index=True)

        print(Report.report)
```

The problem I am facing is that every time I call add_row() from another class the row is overwritten. The code I am talking about:

```
Report.report = Report.report.append(dict_para, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: if its a class, shouldn't it be `self.report` ?  Otherwise, it wouldn't  be stored in that class and only live in function scope i guess.

Comment: Also, a better thing would be if you also create a constructor for creating an instance within the class!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up a couple of things when creating your class. Consider following example

```py
class TestClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.reports = []

  def addReport(self, report):
    self.reports.append(report)


test = TestClass()

test.addReport('one')
test.addReport('two')

print(test.reports) # ['one', 'two']
```

This works as the class is properly initialized with a `__init__` method. In this method the reports array is defined.  Afterwards I invoke the class instructor to get a new instance of that class. With this instance I do my work.

Further, when I want to add to this array via class method, I have to use the `self` keyword. The reason you have to define it in every class function is exactly that, you want to access more stuff from that class and so you need the class itself.